# How to generate wallet and retrieve the bitcoin wallet using RPC

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, rpc, bitcoind

I want to understand how to create a wallet and what is the difference between wallet and addresses, and also how to get back the wallet, just created using RPC. So I'm using PHP and node js for implementation. PHP I'm using a laravel package `denpamusic/laravel-bitcoinrpc`  and node js I am using `request-promise` and I have connected successfully.

```
const   USER = process.env.RPC_USER,
        PASS = process.env.RPC_PASSWORD,
        PORT = process.env.RPC_PORT,//8332
        HOST = process.env.RPC_HOST;//12.1.122.1

async getWalletInfo({req, response}){
    return await rp(requestOption(`{"jsonrpc":"1.0","id":"curltext","method":"getwalletinfo","params":[]}`))
  }
function requestOption(dataString) {
  return {
      url: `http://${USER}:${PASS}@${HOST}:${PORT}/`,
      method: "POST",
      headers: headers,
      body: dataString
  };
}
```

That is the node.js code and below for PHP

```
public function requestNewWallet($block, $wallet){
        switch ($block) {
            case 'bitcoin':
                return $this->bitcoind()->getwalletinfo();
            default:
                return null;
        }
}
```

it gives given the same error

`Denpa\Bitcoin\Exceptions\BadRemoteCallException Wallet file not specified (must request wallet RPC through /wallet/<filename> uri-path)`

So please how do fix this error it is the same on both language

Answer (score 1):

Ok Found The Answer so I have to pass through the wallet for the PHP and for the node.js I have to go through the wallet/{name} endpoint so it looks it `url:` `http://${USER}:${PASS}@${HOST}:${PORT}/wallet/{name}`,

Then PHP Code

```
public function requestNewWallet($block, $wallet){
        switch ($block) {
            case 'bitcoin':
                return $this->bitcoind()->wallet('{dirname}')->getwalletinfo();
            default:
                return null;
        }
}
```